# GWT test with PowerMock and PowerMockito

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a constructor:

```
public PodLinksActivity( PodLinksPlace place ){
   super( MFactory.getView(), place);
    // other methods
}
```

how can I stub the  MFactory.getView() static method with PowerMock or PowerMockito (Mockito) for not making a GWTTestCase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
// view you expect to pass as first super-arg
View view = mock(View.class);

// setup the MFactory class
PowerMockito.mockStatic(MFactory.class);
// mock the method you care about
PowerMockito.when(MFactory.class, "getView").thenReturn(view);
```

Ensure that you add the appropriate PowerMock annotations at the top of your test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MFactory.class)
```

Comment: Similarly, you could also use the stubbing API: stub(method(MFactory.class, "getView")).toReturn(view)